# I want to insert ID with the value being a List containing the Records matching that ID

Tags: java, sql, arraylist, hashmap

```
        ArrayList<Dashboard> dashRec=new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
        HashMap<Object, List<Dashboard>> map = new HashMap<>();
        int x=0;
        Dashboard dash=new Dashboard();
        while(rs.next()) {
            if (x == 0){
                x=rs.getInt(1);
            }
            int  y = rs.getInt(1);
            if(x==y) {
            dashRec=new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
            dash=new Dashboard();
            dash.setREQUEST_ID(rs.getInt(1));
            dash.setLOGIN_USER(rs.getString(2));
            dash.setPRICE(rs.getInt(3));
            dashRec.add(dash);

            }
            if(y!=x){
                dash.getREQUEST_ID();
                dash.getLOGIN_USER();
                map.put(dash,dashRec);
                x=y;
                //1st arraylist is inserted in map.
                ///
            }
```

I want to insert ID with the value being a List containing the Records matching that ID.I have done it for first set of rows. How to do it for n rows?Suppose for next two rows I want another list to be added in map.Similarly for n set of rows I want logic.

[image: SQL db]

Comment: If iam not wrong you are asking      123 , [123,A,5] ,[123,A,10], [123,A,15]   kind of data to be in the map ?

Comment: No,I want 123 as key.Rest  three rows as objects in arraylist.So map must have [id,arraylist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Map like this

```
        Map<Integer, List<Dashboard>> map = new HashMap<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Integer id = rs.getInt(1);
            if (!map.containsKey(id)) {
                map.put(id, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            Dashboard dash = new Dashboard();
            dash.setREQUEST_ID(id);
            dash.setLOGIN_USER(rs.getString(2));
            dash.setPRICE(rs.getInt(3));
            map.get(id).add(dash);
        }
```

Comment: I am checking if the map does not contain the key and assign `new ArrayList<>()` to the id, after that I am grantee that I have ArrayList related to that id, then add the object to the `ArrayList`

Comment: I want 123 as key.Rest three rows as objects in arraylist.So map must have [id,arraylist].SO is it possible through the above code?

Comment: @Aziz Yes it will

Comment: @Aziz Could you plz approve the answer

Comment: As you can see I have initialized Arraylist of type dashboard,so I want to insert objects of each unique id in that particular arraylist.How to so?

Comment: Can you answer this question? It is relevant to your mentioned code. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61585028/get-attributes-value-from-sql-database-as-user-defined-object-in-hashmap

Comment: Ok, sure I will :)