# Get attributes value from sql database as user defined object in hashmap

Tags: java, sql, object, arraylist, hashmap

```
public class Dashboard {
   int REQUEST_ID, PRICE, PROCESSED;           
   String LOGIN_USER;

public int getREQUEST_ID() {
   return REQUEST_ID;
}

public void setREQUEST_ID(int rEQUEST_ID) {
   REQUEST_ID = rEQUEST_ID;
}

//all getters and setters
public class DBConnection {
   public ArrayList<Dashboard>  getStoreResult() {
      ArrayList<Dashboard> dashRec;

   try{
      Class.forName("");
      Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("");
      Statement st=con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("");

      HashMap<Object, List<Dashboard>> map = new HashMap<>();
      while (rs.next()) {
        Integer id = rs.getInt(1);
        if (!map.containsKey(id)) {
            dashRec= new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
            map.put(id, dashRec);
        }
        Dashboard dash = new Dashboard();
        dash.setREQUEST_ID(id);
        dash.setLOGIN_USER(rs.getString(2));
        dash.setPRICE(rs.getInt(3));
        dash.setPROCESSED(rs.getInt(4));
        map.get(id).add(dash);
      }
   }
  }
}
```

I want to add name and status as user defined object in above hashmap. The name must be like **A for first 3 set, B for next 2 set of rows**.The status I want to insert must be lowest number in the set of rows of same ID. That is with ID 123, we need status as 1 to be inserted as object in hashmap and for id 456 we need status 2. How would it be done?

[image: SQL DB]

Comment: The name and status will be added after the reading DB? And why the status of 456 does not start from 1 to 2?

Comment: It's not clear the `lowest number in the set of rows of same ID`, could you explain this

Comment: @sc0der  To clear you,yes name and status will be added after the reading DB.Status can be any number ranging from 1 to 3 for any row.Now for set of rows,here set refers to rows with same id.So id 123 has set of 3 rows and id 456 has set of 2 rows and similarly.Now  lowest number in the set of rows of same ID for suppose 123 is 1 ,for id 456 it is 2,for id 789 it is 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the map after the while-loop like this

check if list size 3, 2, or 1

Base on the your post query there are 3, 2 and 1 rows and I want to

status from 1 to 3 when rows are 3
status from 2 to 3 when rows are 2
status 1 when 1 row

based on this I write a condition to check:

list of size: 3 -> (3-3) +1 = 2

list of size: 2 -> (3-2) +1 = 2

list of size: 1 -> (3-1) +1 = 3

> AtomicInteger

Because I loop over the `Dashboard list` using `Stream` in `Foreach` and if you 
want to access any variables outside this method mark as final.
So I added the Object of AtomicInteger

more information [Atomic Integer Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

```
        // create another map contains the lowest status for each id
        Map<Integer, Integer> lowestStatus = new HashMap<>();
        for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {

            // get the size of the list related to that id
            int size = map.get(key).size();
            int status = (3 - size) + 1;
            final AtomicInteger statusCounter = new AtomicInteger(status);

            if (status != 3) {
                map.get(key).forEach(dashboard -> {
                    if (!lowestStatus.containsKey(key))
                        lowestStatus.put(key, statusCounter.get());

                    dashboard.setStatus(statusCounter.getAndIncrement());
                });

            } else {
                Dashboard dashboard = map.get(key).get(0);
                dashboard.setStatus(1);
                lowestStatus.put(key, 1);
            }
        }
```

, another version

> CurrentStatus

To keep tracking what's the last status when having to that id

> LowestStatus

Save the first occurrence to a given set of rows with a given id will take 1 value

```
        Map<Integer, List<Dashboard>> map = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> lowestStatus = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> currentStatus = new HashMap<>();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Integer id = rs.getInt(1);
            if (!map.containsKey(id)) {
                map.put(id, new ArrayList<Dashboard>());
                currentStatus.put(id, 0);
                lowestStatus.put(id, 1);
            }
            Dashboard dash = new Dashboard();
            dash.setRequestId(id);
            dash.setLoginUser(rs.getString(2));
            dash.setPrice(rs.getInt(3));
            dash.setProcessed(rs.getInt(4));
            dash.setStatus(currentStatus.get(id) + 1);
            currentStatus.put(id, currentStatus.get(id) + 1); // update the status for the next iteration
            map.get(id).add(dash);
        }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213463/discussion-on-answer-by-sc0der-get-attributes-value-from-sql-database-as-user-de).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement clearly, you want to sort the `Map` in the ascending order of the `requestId` and then sort the list of `Dashboard` records with the same `requestId` in ascending order of `status`. If so, given below is the solution for the same:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;

class Dashboard {
    private int requestId, price, processed;
    String loginUser;

    public Dashboard(int requestId, String loginUser, int price, int processed) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
        this.price = price;
        this.processed = processed;
        this.loginUser = loginUser;
    }

    public int getRequestId() {
        return requestId;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getProcessed() {
        return processed;
    }

    public String getLoginUser() {
        return loginUser;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return requestId + "\t" + price + "\t" + processed + "\t" + loginUser;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Object, List<Dashboard>> map = new TreeMap<>();
        List<Dashboard> list;

        list = new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
        list.add(new Dashboard(456, "B", 25, 2));
        list.add(new Dashboard(456, "B", 20, 3));
        map.put(456, list);

        list = new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
        list.add(new Dashboard(123, "A", 10, 2));
        list.add(new Dashboard(123, "A", 15, 3));
        list.add(new Dashboard(123, "A", 5, 1));
        map.put(123, list);

        list = new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
        list.add(new Dashboard(789, "C", 30, 1));
        map.put(789, list);

        // Sort the list of Dashboard records with the same requestId in ascending order
        // of status
        for (Entry<Object, List<Dashboard>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Collections.sort(entry.getValue(), Comparator.comparing(Dashboard::getProcessed));
        }

        // Display Result
        System.out.println("reqid\tname\tprice\tstatus");
        for (List<Dashboard> recordList : map.values()) {
            for (Dashboard record : recordList) {
                System.out.println(record.getRequestId() + "\t" + record.getLoginUser() + "\t" + record.getPrice()
                        + "\t" + record.getProcessed());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
reqid   name    price   status
123     A       5       1
123     A       10      2
123     A       15      3
456     B       25      2
456     B       20      3
789     C       30      1
```

**Notes:**

1. I have used [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) which is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys. Since the keys are `int requestId`, we don't need to do anything to compare them. The `TreeSet` will automatically take care of keeping them in ascending order.
2. To sort the list of `Dashboard` records with the same `requestId` in ascending order of `status`, I have got the list of `Dashboard` records using the `requestId` as the key and then sorted the `List` using `Comparator.comparing(Dashboard::getProcessed)`.